# How to alter font style after keyframes animation in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am looking for some help with my animations in CSS. I have the following text effect but after it has finished, I want to change my font size and color. I tried adding these details into the keyframes but nothing happened:

```
@keyframes shine {
0% {
    background-position-x: -500%; 

   }

100% {
     background-position-x: 500%;
     background-color: red;
     font-size: 50px;
    }
  }
```

Is it possible that I need to start another animation after the first one is complete?

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#333641">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="text_reveal.css">
        <title>Luminance</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
        <div class = "contact-container">
        <div class = "contact-text">
            <span><h2>This is my heading</h2></span>
            <span><p>This is my text.</p></span>
            <button class="btn2"><b>Contact Me</b></button>
        </div> 
        </div>       

    </body>
```

My CSS:

```
.contact-container {
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
  } 
    
.contact-text h2 {
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;   
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #000, #fff, #000);
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 80%;
    animation: shine 5s linear;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    position: relative;  
}
     
.contact-text p {
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Hack, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #000, #fff, #000);
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 80%;
    animation: shine 5s linear infinite;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    position: relative;
}
   
    @keyframes shine {
    0% {
        background-position-x: -500%;        
       }

    100% {
         background-position-x: 500%;
        }
      }
```

Comment: Look p animation-fill-mode: forwards

Comment: thank you. `animation-fill-mode:forwards` led me to the desired outcome.